# Trying to iterate and sort items into a tree view within MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a large list of items that need to be seperated into a tree view.
Each item separates into a Category > Subject > Item.
Each item also has a user that it is assigned to.

This is my current **View**, which simply lists them all out with who each item is assigned to. It gets the job done but is not as tidy as I would like:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tabcategories">
   <ul>
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.ItemName,"Item",new {ItemId = item.ItemId })<span class="uppercase">@item.AssignedTo</span></li>
       }
   </ul>
</div>
```

My **Model** is as follows:

```
    public partial class ItemList
{
    public ItemList()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public class Category
    {
        public String CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        public Category(string categoryName)
        {
            Subjects = new List<Subject>();
            CategoryName = categoryName;
        }

    }
    public class Subject
    {
        public String SubjectName { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public Subject(string subjectName)
        {
            Items = new List<Item>();
            SubjectName = subjectName;
        }

    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public Item(string itemName, int itemId)
        {
            ItemName = itemName;
            ItemId = itemId;
        }
    }
}
```

My **Actionresult** currently checks what privileges the user has on the website and returns the appropriate layout with the information from a database stored procedure.

```
        public ActionResult ItemList()
    {
        UAC Uac = new UAC();
        if (Uac.GetUserPrivileges(TrimUserName(User.Identity.Name)) > 3)
        {
            if (Uac.GetUserPrivileges(TrimUserName(User.Identity.Name)) > 5)
            {
                return View("ItemListEdits", "_AdminLayout", db.spGetCompleteItemList().ToList().OrderBy(itemlist => itemlist.ItemName));
            }
            else
            {
                return View("ItemListEdits", "_Layout2", db.spGetCompleteItemList().ToList().OrderBy(itemlist => itemlist.ItemName));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("ItemList", "_Layout", db.spGetCompleteItemList().ToList().OrderBy(itemlist => itemlist.ItemName));
        }
```

What would be the best way to iterate through these items so that I can have them look like this example: [Desired Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMwmy.jpg)

I have searched and found a few things close to what I need but being rather new to MVC I have not been able to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without the razor stuff you need a structure like:

```
        ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
        // fill up your itemList
        foreach (ItemList.Category category in itemList.Categories)
        {
            // output category name here
            foreach (ItemList.Subject subject in category.Subjects)
            {
                // output subject name here
                foreach (ItemList.Item item in subject.Items)
                {
                   // output item name here
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Still having trouble getting it to work, added my action result.

Comment: Could you try to specify more precisely your problem. Your question was how to iterate through your items and I think I answered that.